# 404 errors on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, url

I have run a link checker on my site and it came up with this link:

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
```

I confirm this URL is not valid. How do I isolate why did bad link is in the site? Is it an issue with the WordPress core?  The theme? I tried looking in the theme code and I can't find it.

Comment: What "link checker" were you using? The reported "error" is really a fault /limitation of the link checker. Note the `rel="dns-prefetch"` attribute.

Comment: I used https://www.htmlvalidator.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to view the site `fonts.googleapis.com` in a browser, you might think it is not a valid URL, but it is actually used to load Google fonts in the background of your WordPress site.  This might be via a theme or a style sheet.

For a more detailed explanation https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-waiting-fonts-googleapis-com/